# ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

В поиске решения - в соседней теме подсказали как верно реализовать задачу. Реализовал, работает частично. Проблема в одном: По какой-то причине *((int)property.Order* по всем позициям равен 10000. Хотя в базе и в помине нет у данного логина этих значений...

View:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<Resource> Localizer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = @Localizer["Achievement.Achievements"];
}

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @foreach (Web.Models.DataBase.Achievements info in ViewBag.info)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default inf-content">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                    <div class="text-muted pull-left"><h4>@Localizer["Achievement.Achievements"]</h4></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body text-muted">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="row">
                        @await Html.PartialAsync("_AccountMenu")

                        @await Html.PartialAsync("_Achievements", info)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Partial:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<Resource> Localizer
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding

@{
    Dictionary<string, int> Achs = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
{"Achievement1", 3 },
{"Achievement2", 300 },
{"Achievement3", 500000 },
{"Achievement4", 150 },
{"Achievement5", 50000 },
{"Achievement6", 1000 },
{"Achievement7", 1000 },
{"Achievement8", 50 },
{"Achievement9", 25 },
{"Achievement10", 25 },
{"Achievement11", 10 },
{"Achievement12", 75 },
{"Achievement13", 250 },
{"Achievement14", 250 },
{"Achievement15", 300 },
{"Achievement16", 300 },
{"Achievement17", 300 },
{"Achievement18", 100 },
{"Achievement19", 100 },
{"Achievement20", 500 },
{"Achievement21", 500 },
{"Achievement22", 100 },
{"Achievement23", 100 },
{"Achievement24", 100000 },
{"Achievement25", 30 },
{"Achievement26", 5 },
{"Achievement27", 10 },
{"Achievement28", 5 },
{"Achievement29", 50 },
{"Achievement30", 30 },
{"Achievement31", 3 },
{"Achievement32", 300 },
{"Achievement33", 300 },
{"Achievement34", 300 },
{"Achievement35", 300 },
{"Achievement36", 300 },
{"Achievement37", 300 },
{"Achievement38", 300 },
{"Achievement39", 300 },
{"Achievement40", 300 },
{"Achievement41", 3 },
{"Achievement42", 300 },
{"Achievement43", 300 },
{"Achievement44", 300 },
{"Achievement45", 300 },
{"Achievement46", 300 },
{"Achievement47", 300 },
{"Achievement48", 300 },
{"Achievement49", 300 },
{"Achievement50", 300 }
};
    int title = 1;
    int info = 1;
}

@foreach (ModelMetadata property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    if (property.PropertyName.StartsWith("Achievement"))
    {
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 text-center">
                        <img src="@string.Format("/images/achievements/{0}.png", property.PropertyName)" alt="Achievement"
                             class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9 section-box">
                        <span class="ach-title-size">
                            @Localizer["Achievement.Title" + title++]
                            @if ((int)property.Order >= Achs[property.PropertyName] / 3)
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
                            }
                            @if ((int)property.Order >= Achs[property.PropertyName] / 3 * 2)
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
                            }
                            @if ((int)property.Order >= Achs[property.PropertyName])
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
                            }
                        </span>
                        <p class="achievement-text-size">
                            @Localizer["Achievement.Info" + info++]
                        </p>
                        @if ((int)property.Order >= Achs[property.PropertyName])
                        {
                            <span class="text-warning">Выполнено!</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <span class="pull-right achievement-text-size">
                                @property.Order<span>/</span>@Achs[property.PropertyName]
                            </span>
                            <div class="row rating-desc">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="achievement-progress">
                                        <progress max="@Achs[property.PropertyName]" value="@((int)(int)property.Order)">
                                        </progress>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Всем заранее спасибо за любой совет!

Comment: этот `property` имеет тип `ModelMetadata`, у которого есть [поле `Order`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.order(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata.Order), которое никаким образом не связано с вашей БД

Comment: Да, уже нашёл информацию. Спасибо. Сейчас ищу решения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ASP.NET Core свойство [ModelMetadata.Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.model(v=vs.118).aspx) изменилось на [ModelMetadata.PropertyGetter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelmetadata.propertygetter?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Это делегат, позволяющий вычислить значение любой произвольной модели, а не какой-то заранее заданной. Вот так: `@property.PropertyGetter(Model)`.